# Bitwise operators return NA

Tags: r, overflow, bitwise-operators, bit

I have the following code snippet:

```
lower_mask = 0x7FFFFFFF
upper_mask = bitwNot(lower_mask)
```

"upper_mask" is NA after running it. I don't know why. If this was an overflow case it would be pretty strange since NOT operator should not overflow and just flip the bits. Can you please explain me what is happening and how can I fix it ? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe using instead package `bitops`?

Comment: I think you are not expecting `bitwNot()` because this is the two´s complement: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#NOT 
and then your number exceeds the 32 bit range: NOT 2147483647 -> -2147483647-1  = -2147483648

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bitwise not of 0x7fffffff is 0x8000000.  Unfortunately for your purposes, that's the encoding used for the integer NA.

R only supports 2^32 - 1 non-NA values, from -.Machine$integer.max to +.Machine$integer.max.  In hex, those are 0x80000001 to 0x7fffffff.

Comment: Is it possible to use 64-bit in R ?

Comment: There are some packages that support large integers, but base R doesn't.  You can get 52 bits using floating point `numeric()` values, and that's what the `bitops` package does, so `bitops::bitFlip(0x7fffffff)` gives `2147483648`.  I'm not sure how to get it to print in hex, but that's equal to `0x80000000`.